# The use of numpy.argmax

Tags: python, numpy

I'm here to inquire about the use of numpy.argmax

For instance, consider this array:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
b = np.argmax(a, axis = 0)
c = np.argmax(a, axis = 1)

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

Here's the output:

```
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]]
5
[1 1 1]
[2 2]
```

I'm confused about the use of the parameter axis for numpy.argmax. What does it do? Why does it return [1 1 1] if axis = 0 and [2 2] if the value of axis = 1?

Comment: Looking at the columns of that array (dimension #0), the maximum value is found in row 1 in all three cases - the 3, 4, and 5.  Looking at the rows (dimension #1), the maximum value is found in column 2 in both cases - the 2 and the 5.

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.argmax()` returns the position of the largest element in an array, optionally by row or column (the `axis` argument). So in the first case, `[1 1 1]`, you get the position of the largest element column-wise. Since the elements in row 1 are all larger that the elements in row 0, you get your array of three ones. Analogously for `axis=1`, where you get the column of the largest element in each row.

Answer (score 0):

argmax returns to you the index of the max value along the axis you specified.

The exact comparisons it did to get there:

3 > 0, 4 > 1, 5 > 2 : `[1 1 1]`

2 is the largest of set `[0 1 2]`
5 is the largest of set `[3 4 5]`:

```
[2 2]
```